# Workaround for 'System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.'

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need a workaround on this issue that I am currently facing. I am retrieving records from the oracle database using Enterprise Library DAAB, but when I reached the `ExecuteReader` method call, I get this error. I checked other links for solutions which says that I need to install the client to be able to fix this but still no avail.

The server which I am connecting to is (i think) of a lower version based on the error. It would be fine if I were to install it, but this is out of my jurisdiction as this is handled by the DBA.

I would like to know if there is any other way for me to retrieve records. Do I need to use the `openquery()` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the required OCI client. Oracle will never give any support unless the setup fully complies to the 'supported configurations' chart.

Another option that is less intrusive than getting a DBA or administrator involved is using the new [Oracle Managed provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) for ADO.NET. This doesn't need an OCI client to be installed.